# "Add to Package" picklist shows "Cross Org Data Hub" - What is it?

Tags: managed-package, environment-hub

When I added components to a package I realized there is a new component type **Cross Org Data Hub**. Is this related to Environment Hub or External Objects?!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Hub is a container of one or more object that you share with other organizations. A hub can share any custom object and Account standard object.

This is a Winter 15 pilot release.